# Read cookie value and fill the value to form fields

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pre-populate multiple form fields by reading cookie data. The code does not seem to split the cookie data into fields instead it grouped them together. I cant seem to figure it out.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>

<script language="JavaScript1.2" type="text/javascript">

  var today = new Date();  
  var expiry = new Date(today.getTime() + 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000); // plus 30 days

  function setCookie(name, value){
    document.cookie=name + "=" + escape(value) + "; path=/; expires=" + expiry.toGMTString();
  }

function putCookie(form){
   setCookie("FirstName", form[0].FirstName.value);
   setCookie("LastName", form[0].LastName.value);

   return true;
  }

</script>


<script language="JavaScript1.2" type="text/javascript">

function ReadCookie(){

if (document.cookie != ""){
        cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            cookie = cookies[i].trim().split("=");
            if (cookie[0] == 'FirstName') {
                document.TestForm.FirstName.value = cookie[1];
            }
            if (cookie[0] == 'LastName') {
                document.TestForm.LastName.value = cookie[1];
            }
        }

}

</script>

</head>

<body onload="ReadCookie()">           

<form name="TestForm">
 <input type="text" value="Enter Your First Name" id="nameBox" name='FirstName'>
 <input type="text" value="Enter Your Last Name" id="nameBox" name='LastName'>

 <input type="button" value="Go!" id="submit" onclick="putCookie(document.getElementsByTagName('form'));">

</form>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please post how the cookie looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly then you are setting a cookie with "FirstName=xxxxx; path=....." and then one with "LastName". `document.cookie` should give you "FirstName=xxxx;LastName=yyyy". I'm not sure if `putCookie()` works all right with this code. Doublecheck that the cookies are really set.

So you first have to split the cookies by ";", loop through the cookies and then get the values by "=". Here is an example that should work with your code:

```
function fillIn(){
    if (document.cookie != ""){
        cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            cookie = cookies[i].trim().split("=");
            if (cookie[0] == 'FirstName') {
                document.form1.FirstName.value = cookie[1];
            }
            if (cookie[0] == 'LastName') {
                document.form1.LastName.value = cookie[1];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also checked for the name of the cookie because there might be other cookies flying around as well. :-)

Comment: that exactly what I need but still wont work see revised code with your sample

Comment: hm, it works for me. is this the original HTML code or do you maybe have more than one form on the page? Can you check in the browser if the cookie is properly set, when you press the button?

Comment: For me it sets cookie fine but when you refresh it should auto fill the form and it does not that. That is the issue I'm having.

Comment: Ah, I think you just forgot one "}" at the end of the function ReadCookie().